XCode - Companion Watch App Not Installing Automatically
I've been working on an iOS app for about six months and recently added a WatchOS companion app. However, when I run the iOS app on my device through Xcode, the Watch companion app doesn't install automatically. Instead, it shows up in 'Available Apps' when I open the Watch app on my iPhone.
I have 'Automatic App Install' enabled for my Watch.
Does anyone know why the companion app isn't installing automatically in this debug scenario?
I've got WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier set to my iOS app bundle identifier and 'WatchOnly' set to NO.

There are a few things I think could be causing the issue, but I can't say exactly forr sure what it would be unfornately,

Check deployment targets under Deployment info to make sure the
versions are all compatible with your devices in case that might
cause an issue
-Check the scheme section, make sure both ios app target and the watchkit are both under the build section
-Try toggling the auto app install on your actual watch, just on and off again and clean install again and see if that might fix it and get it working


